# Can elements of an MVC5 application be compiled as a DLL?

Tags: vb.net, dll, asp.net-mvc-5

VS2013, MVC5, VB, EF6

I've never really created a DLL but will begin learning the 'ins and outs' (no pun intended) on that shortly.  But without that background I don't have the familiarity to understand exactly what is possible regarding DLL's and MVC5.

What can be compiled into a DLL when working in MVC5?

**Controller**:  It would seem the controller could be turned into a DLL for use in other MVC5 applications; is that the case?  Or are there fundamental problems doing that?

**Views**:  Views aren't really methods, per se, right?  The server uses a view file to create pages for transmission, but I don't see how they could be compiled into a DLL.

**Models**:  These are effectively our database, except for View Models.  They obviously are part of the code just as the methods in a controller, and they drive the EF to create databases as required.  But I'm not sure I understand how a model could be a DLL either.

Thanks for any insight into this.

Perhaps there are other better ways to reuse work done on specific parts of an MVC5 application.  Whatever those may be, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DLL is just the result of the compilation of a .NET project. You shouldn't really think of putting things into a DLL as much as just how you should structure your solution (what projects to add, of what type and how many).

For reusable components, you should create a class library project. Here, you can put anything including controllers, entities, view models, etc. Views are trickier because they're not compiled, by default. However, you can use something like [Razor Generator](https://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/), a Nuget package that allows you to compile views and use pre-compiled views in your MVC projects.

Then, once you have your class library set up, you simply add a project reference to any other project in the solution that needs it. When building, the compiler will create a DLL for the class library and drop that into the bin folder of the other project, but again, you needn't actually concern yourself with this.

If you need to share the code with other projects not in the same solution, then you should actually [create a Nuget package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) using your class library project. If your code has use for the world at large, you can publish it publicly on the nuget.org, but you can also publish to a [private repository](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds), instead. This is great because it allows you to share code easily between internal projects.